# Copy the entire contents of a project in a folder of another project, when build (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, copy, xcopy

I've a Visual Studio 2013 solution, within 2 projects PJ1 and PJ2.
My goal is to copy the entire contents of PJ1 in a folder (myFolder) situated under PJ2. In addition, the copy must occur when I perform a build for PJ1.
I tried with xcopy without results:

```
xcopy /E /Y "$(ProjectDir)" "$(SolutionDir)PJ2\myFolder\"
```

Any idea?

Comment: are you facing any problem in post build events ?

Comment: xcopy exited with code 4

Comment: I have posted an answer. That will work out for you. . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this- Assuming PJ2\MyFolder is your output folder

> Copy build assembly and all the components in project PJ1

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)*.*" "$(SolutionDir)LambdaInXdocument\Myfolder" /E /Y
```

> Copy all the files(.cs and others) & directories where .csproj resides-

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)*.*" "$(SolutionDir)LambdaInXdocument\Myfolder" /E /Y
```

Comment: Performing xcopy "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)*.*" "$(SolutionDir)PJ2\myFolder" /E /Y, it copy just PJ1.dll , PJ1.dll.config and PJ1.pdb

Comment: This command will copy all the files existing in the source folder. ie. your PJ1 build folder. It would help to understand better, if you can tell whats more you want to copy  ?

Comment: as your command says, you want to copy all the files( including .cs & all others) and directories in your project PJ1 to Project PJ2\MyFolder directory. Is it what you want ?

Comment: Ok, I have edited the answer. 2nd one suits your requirement.

Comment: Excellent! It works for me! Thanks. An additional detail: how can I exclude files .csproj or with other extensions from copy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71576/discussion-between-pinturikkio-and-rohit-prakash).